Spring Boot transactional event listener with firestore is not working
Maybe someone knows how to implement a transactional event lister for an event which comes from a firestore snapshot listener?!
This function is started after application startup:
@Override
public void afterSingletonsInstantiated() {
    db.collection("events")
            .addSnapshotListener(
                    setupSnapshotEventListener());
}

private EventListener<QuerySnapshot> setupSnapshotEventListener() {
    return (snapshot, ex) -> {
        if (ex == null && snapshot != null) {
            for (DocumentChange dc : snapshot.getDocumentChanges()) {
                publishFirestoreEvent(dc);
            }
        }
    };
}

private void publishFirestoreEvent(DocumentChange dc) {
    if (dc.getType() == ADDED) {
        var eventEntry = dc.getDocument().toObject(EventEntry.class);
        var event = eventMapper.mapToDomain(eventEntry);
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(event); // Standard ApplicationEventPublisher from Spring Boot
    }
}

This function is located in a service class and is executed, if you set a breakpoint it will stop.
@EventListener
public void handleObjectCreatedEvent(ObjectCreatedEvent event) {
    ...
}

The same function is not executed, if you set a breakpoint it will not stop at this position
also logs are not written.
@Transactional
@EventListener
public void handleObjectCreatedEvent(ObjectCreatedEvent event) {
    ...
}

Why it is not executed adding @Transactional?
Setting parameters in @Transactional und using of @TransactionalEventlistener won't help.
